# Loop through an array and return different html tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array of four strings (the length is always four) where sometimes one of them can be replaced by an array of strings (two or three) like so:

```
array = [
  0: "string0",
  1: "string1",
  2: [
    0: "substring0",
    1: "substring1"
  ],
  3: "string3"
```

I want to loop through them and return different HTML tags according to their type (string or object): when it's a string I want to return a 'p' tag but when it's an array I also want a 'p' tag and a 'span' for each substring.
Basically, I want something like this:

```
<p>string0</p>
<p>string1</p>
<p><span>substring0</span> / <span>substring1</span></p>
<p>string3</p>
```

Here's my current code to access the array above:

```
Object.values(Object.values(Object.entries(obj)[toggle][1])[i])[0]
```

When I add [0] it returns 'string0' so I tried doing a for loop and using the index to return an HTML but it was stopping its execution at the first item. I also tried to use a map but it wasn't working as I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  "string0",
  "string1",
  ["substring0", "substring1"],
  "string3"
]

function wrap(tag, s) {
  return `<${tag}>${s}</${tag}>`
}

console.log(arr.map(i=>wrap('p', 
  Array.isArray(i) ? i.map(j=>wrap('span', j)).join(' / ') : i
)))
```

Comment: If you like the answer and it works for you, please upvote it :-)